# Calling a REST web service secured with Spring Security from Android

Tags: java, web-services, spring, rest, spring-security

I'm hosting a REST web service in a Grails application, using Spring Security, i.e.:

```
@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'])
def save = {
    println "Save Ride REST WebMethod called"
}
```

I'm calling it from an Android app.  (Calling the unsecured service works just fine.)

To call the service, I'm manually building up a request (`HttpUriRequest`) and executing it with an `HttpClient`.

I'm wondering what the best practices are, and how to implement them... Specifically, should I:

1. Perform a login once, to retrieve a JSESSION_ID, then add a header containing it into the HttpUriRequest for each subsequent request?
2. Or (not sure how I would even do this) include the login and password directly on each request, foregoing the cookie/server-side session

I think I can get option 1 working, but am not sure if Spring Security permits (2), if that's the way to go...  Thanks!

--also, there isn't any library I'm missing that would do all this for me is there? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring security *does* support both basic authentication and form based authentication (embedding the username/password in the URL).

A REST service is generally authenticated on each and every request, not normally by a session. The default spring security authentication (assuming you're on 3.x) should look for basic authentication parameters or form parameters (j_username and j_password) (in the form http://you.com/rest_service?j_username=xyz&j_password=abc).

Manually tacking the j_username/j_password onto the URL, adding them as post parameters (I believe), or setting the basic authentication username/password should all work to authenticate a REST service against the default Spring Security interceptors, right out of the box.

I will admit that I haven't tried this on REST services, though I do clearly recall reading exactly this in the docs as I did the same for basic page logins on spring security recently. Disclaimer over.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, this was close (the ideas helped a lot) but didn't work out of the box - I made a post on what it took to get it working: http://storypodders.com/dasBlog/2011/01/22/SecuringRESTServicesInGrailsWithSpringSecurity.aspx

Comment: That was a great post, thanks for contributing it, I'm certain it will be found and useful to many others.

Comment: Putting username and password in the URL is usually considered a bad idea. Webserver log files often contain query parameters which would expose your credentials. Anyone accessing your RESTful service from a browser would have credentials exposed in their history.

Answer (score 9):

I think you can use a login-once-and-get-a-token method that's similar to how oauth works.

sending username and password across the network outside of secured channel(https/ssl) is a terrible idea. anyone on the network can sniff your request package and see the clear text password.

on the other hand, if you use a token method, since the token string is randomly generated, even the token is compromised, the worst case is someone can use the token accessing your REST API.

another solution is going through ssl tunnel(HTTPS). i have actually done a comparison and result shows: 80 requests/min(https) vs 300 requests/min(http)