# How to make Spring-based app work with jsessionid URL parameter

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, sessionid

We have app with REST API. It is based on Spring, Spring security is used as well. 
For example, we configured some role-based restrictions:

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/auth/authenticate" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/auth/logout" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/users/**" access="USER"/>
</sec:http>
```

It works fine with cookies, but now we need to enable the possibility to pass jsessionid as URL param instead of cookies. I thought we don't need to change anything in our code, but something goes wrong. 
I request /login method and copy jsessionid from response. After that I try to request 
/users;jsessionid=*** and got 401 status code, this means that application didn't recognize me. What should we change in order to make this approach work?

Comment: What happen if you disable the cookies in your browser, and then login?

Comment: I got correct JSON response like {"result":{"status":"SUCCESS","message":"Request Succeeded","timestamp":1329740163355},"data":{"email":"user@***.com","roles":["USER"]}} and header to set jsessionid cookies

Comment: Let me summarize: the JSessionID works in the browser but not in your rest client?

Comment: This response is generated by our controller of course. As cookies are  disabled, I got 401 when try to access /companies;jsessionid=...

Comment: No, as URL parameter it doesn't work at all. It works only if set in cookies

Comment: Which server do you use (version), do you use any proxy?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7955/discussion-between-mikhail-and-ralph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, a cookies based authentication system is not good for XML based APIs (like SOAP and REST). The practice is to authenticate on every API call.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664384/calling-a-rest-web-service-secured-with-spring-security-from-android) post in the same forum. Quoting the post :

> A REST service is generally authenticated on each and every request,
>   not normally by a session.

Now the reasons for this is

- The clients or consumers for these type of xml bases APIs are not browsers but other applications.
- Browser understand cookies, in fact cookies are aimed for browser based users but not the applications in general.
- The Client may or may not understand cookie and in most of the cases will NOT understand as Cookies is not a standard approach for authentications for these type of APIs.

There are better ways than handling this in non-standard cookie way. Not sure which version of spring-security you are using, [HERE](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/) is an example of spring-security 3.1 used to secure a RESTful application.

EDIT:

Check out [this link](http://jf.omnis.ch/archives/2004/12/disabling-session-cookie-in-tomcat.html). This forces tomcat (not sure if you use tomcat) to not handle session using cookies. But once done, this will not handle cookie based session. I am not 100% sure it will work, you can try nonetheless.

Comment: I absolutely agree that cookies based authentication system is not good for REST, but this is not our decision. For now we need to make work mechanism with jsessionId in URL instead of cookies

Comment: It won't be easy and sure not out of box. The jsessionid appended URLs arae generated by the container and it knows how to handle them. For the REST urls, they are not generated and hence the server is not prepared to handle them.

Comment: So your requirement is: it should decide runtime, if the cookies are supported and then use cookie else use url rewriting ?